Using javascript template file, how can I check for a null or an undefined value?
I am using a Javascript HTML template engine.  How do I check for null or undefined in my HTML?
If ctx.m.transferTicket is null or undefined, I want to treat that as being false.
SO I have this code
{% if (ctx.m.transferTicket===false || ctx.m.transferTicket=='') { %}
    <div>NOT TRANSFERRED</div>

{% } else { %}
    <div>TRANSFERRED</div>
{% } %}

But if ctx.m.transferTicket is null or undefined, it acts as if it's true.
How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Have you tried it like this?
{% if (ctx.m.transferTicket) { %}
    <div>TRANSFERRED</div>

{% } else { %}
    <div>NOT TRANSFERRED</div>
{% } %}


You do not seem to check for null or undefined though.
{% if (ctx.m.transferTicket === false || ctx.m.transferTicket === null || ctx.m.transferTicket === undefined || ctx.m.transferTicket === '') { %}
    <div>NOT TRANSFERRED</div>
{% } else { %}
    <div>TRANSFERRED</div>
{% } %}

ctx.m.transferTicket === null checks for null
ctx.m.transferTicket === undefined checks for undefined.
